# CString wrote as an unsigned char

Tags: vc90

I am building an application to read and write to a microchip`s memory.

I need to pass an unsigned char array that has 4 fixed bytes and 2 variable bytes so suposing I want to read memory bank 0004 I will pass

```
unsigned char sRequest[32]={0};
sRequest[0] = 0x02; //FIXED
sRequest[1] = 0x1F; //FIXED
sRequest[2] = 0x0A; //FIXED
sRequest[3] = 0x20; //FIXED
sRequest[4] = 0x00; //VARIABLE
sRequest[5] = 0x04; //VARIABLE
```

I want to put 2 CEdit boxes for the user to input that variable memory bank, so it would write 0x00 on first CEdit and 0x04 on second one.

so my question is, how can I translate eacho of these inputs on an unsigned char so I can set it on my sRequest variable?

thanks in advance
(thanks dave, mistyped bytes into bits, fixed now)

Comment: Do you mean bits or bytes? That array has 32 fixed bits, and 16 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wouldn't do that with free-form text entry at all - it would be too much of a bother to do validation (being inherently lazy). If there's a chance to restrict what your user is able to give you as early as possible, you should take it :-)

I would provide drop-down boxes for the values, each nybble so that the quantity to select from is not too onerous. Something like (and with apologies for my graphical skills):

```
               +---+-+  +---+-+  +---+-+  +---+-+
Enter value 0x | 0 |V|  | 0 |V|  | 0 |V|  | 4 |V|
               +---+-+  +---+-+  +---+-+  +---+-+
               |>0<|
               | 1 |
               | 1 |
               | 2 |
               | 3 |
               : : :
               | E |
               | F |
               +---+
```

For the values in the listbox, I would set the item data to be 0 through 15 inclusive (for the items `0` through `F`).

That way, you could get a single byte value with something like:

```
byte04 = listboxA.GetItemData(listboxA.GetCurSel()) * 16 +
         listboxB.GetItemData(listboxB.GetCurSel());

byte05 = listboxC.GetItemData(listboxC.GetCurSel()) * 16 +
         listboxD.GetItemData(listboxD.GetCurSel());
```

---

If you *must* use a less restrictive input method, C++ provides:

```
int stoi (const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

(and `stol/stoul` for signed and unsigned longs) to allow you to convert C++ strings to integral types.

For your purposes. you'll probably have to detect and strip a leading `0x` (along with possibly leading/trailing spaces and so forth) which is why I suggest the restrictive route as a better option.

Comment: your graphical skills are good enough =) thanks for your answer but even if I made it that way how could I get those values translated in one char (two actually)? Im not concerned about the user entry, because this is just for my engineer to test his chip, therefore he will know what to write.

Comment: @Mateus, I've added a short bit in there on one way to convert individual CListBox items into usable byte values.